# borderlessButtonStyle on Android SDK 9

Tags: android, xml

`notification_media_action.xml` in `appcompat_v7` uses

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

But `Lint` says

> ?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle requires API level 11 (current min
>   is 9)

`themes_base.xml` contains

```
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
```

`style_base.xml` contains:

```
<!-- Borderless ink button -->
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_btn_borderless_material</item>
</style>

<!-- Bordered ink button -->
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">88dip</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

Is it possible to construct a **standalone** `borderlessButtonStyle` from the above, which would work on Android sdk 9?

Comment: Yes, you would have to create your own style and use that. You could use the android styles as a starting point for your style. It will probably not behave or act that same, but you might get close enough.

Comment: try to set: `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` on your view